# knitr cache: update if data file changes but not other options (e.g., `fig.xyz`)

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

Suppose that I use `knitr`, I have a chunk which takes a while to run, I want this chunk to update if a file changes but not if I e.g., change `fig.path`. The later suggest that I should change the `cache` [chunk option to 1](https://yihui.name/knitr/demo/cache/) but then I cannot use a check sum as suggested [here](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/238#issuecomment-5757938).

Here is an example of a markdown file

````r
---
title: "Example"
author: "Benjamin Christoffersen"
date: "September 2, 2018"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
data_file <- "~/data.RDS"
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, cache.extra = tools::md5sum(data_file))
```

```{r load_data}
dat <- readRDS(data_file)
```

```{r large_computation, cache = 1}
Sys.sleep(10)
Sys.time() # just to that result do not change
```

```{r make_some_plot}
hist(dat)
```
````

Running `set.seed(1): saveRDS(rnorm(100), "~/data.RDS")` and knitting yields

[image]

Then running `set.seed(2): saveRDS(rnorm(100), "~/data.RDS")` and knitting yields

[image]

showing that `large_computation` is not updated as is should not since `cache.extra` is not in the `knitr:::cache1.opts` vector. Of course, I can save the `md5sum` result, check the previous stored file and use `cache.rebuild` or do something similar in the `large_computation` chunk but it would be nice with a `knitr` solution. I often find that I change some chunk options (e.g., `dpi`, `fig.width`, and `fig.height`) so using `cache = TRUE` will not work. I guess one could modify the package to be able to add options to `knitr:::cache1.opts`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, the problem is that `cache.extra` is not taken into account if `cache` is set to `1`. In fact, [this is by design](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/994).

The desired behavior is to invalidate the cache of all chunks (including chunks with `cache = 1`) if an external file (or more general: some value provided to `cache.extra`) changes.

As mentioned in the question, one way to achieve this is using the [chunk option `cache.rebuild`](https://yihui.name/knitr/options/#cache) but instead of manually keeping track of changes in the external file, I'd take advantage if knitr's built-in caching capabilies:

````
```{r cachecontrol, cache = TRUE, cache.extra = tools::md5sum(data_file)}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(cache.rebuild = TRUE)
```
````

Adding this as an early chunk, the cache of all subsequent chunks is invalidated if `data_file` changes. The idea is to *cache the chunk that controls caching of subsequent chunks* – but only if the external file is unchanged.

Of course, this only works if no global chunk options are changed before the `cachecontrol` chunk is evaluated.

---

Full example from the question:

Run `set.seed(1); saveRDS(rnorm(100), "data.RDS")` with different seeds to generate different external files, then knit:

````
---
title: "Invalidate all chunks condidional on external file (even if cache=1)"
output: html_document
---

```{r}
data_file <- "data.RDS"
```

```{r cachecontrol, include = FALSE, cache = TRUE, cache.extra = tools::md5sum(data_file)}
# do NOT change global chunk options before this chunk
knitr::opts_chunk$set(cache.rebuild = TRUE)
```

```{r setup, include = FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, fig.width = 8)
```


```{r load_data}
dat <- readRDS(data_file)
```

```{r large_computation, cache = 1}
Sys.sleep(10)
Sys.time() # just to show that result do not change unless external file changes
```

```{r make_some_plot}
hist(dat)
```
````

Comment: But the `cachecontrol` chunk is invalidated if I e.g., change `fig.width` in `knitr::opts_chunk$set` so I do not archive the desired result. I only want to invalidate the chunks if something in `knitr:::cache1.opts` change or the `data_file`.

Comment: It might work if one change the order in which the two `knitr::opts_chunk$set` calls are made.

Comment: @BenjaminChristoffersen Yup, just change the order of the chunks. You could avoid the problem altogether if you changed all global options only after the `lage_computation` chunk. Personally, I prefer a separation of concerns: I compute results in early (potentially cached) chunks (before the "main text"), store the results in variables and do all the plotting / printing / formatting stuff in later chunks within the main body of the text. In-between you could change global options without affecting the  cache of earlier chunks.

Comment: Thanks. I prefer the former as it makes the flow of the document more natural with some computation, printing of output/results, computation, printing of output/results, etc. My first comments do not make sense after you changed your answer and corrected the order as I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution to the ignorance of cache.extra when cache=1 or 2.
Please insert the following [hook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/option-hooks.html) code to the setup section, which inserts extra comment to a code section to invalidate a cache when the cache.extra is changed.

```r
knitr::opts_hooks$set(cache.extra = function(options){
  # invalidate cache 
  options$code <- c(sprintf("# cache.extra: %s", options$cache.extra), options$code)
  options
})
```